# Get css code of website with file()

Tags: php

I've got this code:

```
$path = $site."/".$stylesheets[0] ("http://example.com/thecssfile.css")
$css = file($path);
```

But now, there is the sourcecode of **http://example.com** in the $css variable. How can I get the code of **http://example.com/thecssfile.css**. If I set the $path variable directly to **"http://example.com/thecssfile.css"** it works but I want it dynamic.

Comment: There are plenty questions about parsing HTML in any language - makes sure to search to demonstrate that you've tried to find solution already (you may even find answer to your question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Yes, I tried this allready. My way works but not dynamic

Comment: If you've already tried to parse HTML and get links (and that did not work for your case) you need to clarify what "dynamic" means for you.

Comment: I try to get the code of all css files on a website, which was choosen by the user. The stylesheet names are different. So the path must be different for all sites (dynamic)

Comment: @Tom291: You need to parse the HTML and find the `<link>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You assume, that `$stylesheets[0]` is `thecssfile.css`, but it is not. You can see this by `var_dump($stylesheets[0])`

You need to make sure, it has the value you want. In your case:

```
$stylesheets = [0 => 'thecssfile.css']
```

Comment: the css file is called **/s1077.css** and the outout of var_dump is:

Comment: string(16) "/s1077.css
"